# Relation between eigenvalue and the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Consider the $0$ matrix. It has one eigenvalue: $0$, and the dimension of its eigenspace is $n$, since it sends everything to $0$. If I have $n$ distinct eigenvalues, one of them zero, then the eigenspace for $0$ must have dimension $1$, hence the rank is $n−1$.

So is my conclusion right:

If the a linear transformation T has only one eigenvalue ${\lambda }$= $0$, then dim(ker($T$)) = $1$?

Comment: Vectors in the nullspace are not linearly independent (in particular, the nullspace always contains $0$); but it is possible to find a basis (thus a linearly independent *subset*) of the nullspace. The same is true for eigenvectors : all eigenvectors of $T$ for a fixed eigenvalue are not linearly independent, but it possible to find a basis (which is thus a linearly independent *subset*).

Comment: Thanks, so is my conclusion right?

Comment: Well I don't understand what you mean by $\ker(T)=1$. Do you mean the dimension?

Comment: Well yes I guess, if the only eigenvalue is 0, them the dim (ker T) = 1?

Comment: No. $0$ could be multiple eigenvalue (see answer below).

Answer (score 2):

If $0$ is an eigenvalue for the linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$, then by the definitions of eigenspace and kernel you have

$$V_0=\{v\in V| T(v)=0v=0\}=\text{ker}T.$$

If you have only one eigenvalue, which is $0$ the dimension of $\text{ker}T$ is equal to the dimension of $V_0$.

For instance: consider the endomorphism, whose associated matrix respect to the canonical base is:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}

the the only eigenvalue is $0$, but the dimension of the kernel is $2$.